# How to specify the "file" element in the "Additional Manifest Dependencies" linker option of Visual Studio

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, manifest

I am trying to embed a manifest file into a win32 dll, to depend on a specific version of TestComp.dll, for this i am using manifest file and  i am able to embed the manifest file into an assembly using the MT.exe and it works fine, so now i want to embed the same manifest with the Visual studio project settings, to avoid have a additional .manifest file.

my current MainDll.Manifest file looks like this

[image]

in the Visual Studio ->**Configuration Properties**->**Linker->Manifest File ->Additional Manifest Dependencies**
i specified the following

**/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='TTK.MYCOMP.TestComp' version='1.5.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86'**

The generated manifest file looked very similar,obviously missing the file element, i am unable to figure out how to provide the file element with the name of the dll in the /manifestdependency linker switch

Thank you for taking time out to look into this issue.

Comment: I don't think the editor can do everything you can do with a file. But you don't need to use mt.exe or special build steps. Just add a .manifest file (for ex: app.manifest) to the project and compilation will automatically merge its content into the final manifest resource of the .dll.

Comment: i wanted to avoid the manifest file and use the settings stored in the project file, if this is not possible ,then i guess i will have to use this option. thanks for the reply.